# Using HandVU with OpenCV on Mac OS X 10.6.3

Tags: macos, opencv, segmentation-fault

I've tried to user HandVU with OpenCV but when I tried to run "hvOpenCV config/default.conductor" I get a "Segmentation fault". Anybody know this problem?

```
macbook:handvu-beta3 User$ hvOpenCV config/default.conductor 
will load conductor from file:
config/default.conductor
Segmentation fault
```

I installed OpenCV through http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port on Mac OS X 10.6.3, and HandVU through http://www.movesinstitute.org/~kolsch/HandVu/doc/InstallationLinux.html#source

I think it's a problem with opencv, because if I'm trying to run the peopledetect example, I get a segmentation fault too.

```
macbook:c User$ ./peopledetect pic1.png
Segmentation fault
```

And if I try to run the facedetect sample I get an error too:

```
macbook:c User$ ./facedetect --cascade="../../haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" 
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "/tmp/launch-WUMho1/org.x:0".
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to compiling OpenCV on MacOSX 10.6, and this may solve the issue...

First, from http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port , compile in i386 mode by issueing

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv
cd opencv # the directory containing INSTALL, CMakeLists.txt etc.
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=i386 -D CMAKE_C/CXX_FLAGS=-m32 -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_LATEX_DOCS=ON ..
make -j2
sudo make install
```

Eventually, I had to rebuild some ports:

```
sudo port install ilmbase +universal
port provides /opt/local/lib/libIlmImf.dylib
sudo port install openexr +universal
```

and recompile openCV

Then I could run python examples

```
cd ../samples/python/
python camera.py
```

and `facedetect` with no error (and webcam working).

Comment: I am also using HomeBrew now: gives a quick way to compile opencv with a similar route.

Answer (score 0):

Compile OpenCV with QTKit and Cocoa and then use it with HandVu. If you using Mac OSX 10.6.4 and above then please follow the steps below. (I assume you got PKG_CONFIG_PATH already setup)

1. Compile OpenCV with QTKit and Cocoa ( dont select WITH_QUICKTIME and WITH_CARBON options in cmake configurations ). Additionally use TBB if you have it but its optional.
2. Get HandVu sources and then change the following files:

   - `handvu/HandVu.h` ( replace `#include "cv.h"` with `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` and remove "highgui.h" )
   - handvu/OpticalFlow.h ( replace #include "cv.h" with #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" and remove "highgui.h" )
   - handvu/GestureServer.cpp ( on line 255, replace MSG_NOSIGNAL with SO_NOSIGPIPE )
   - hv_OpenCV/hv_OpenCV.cpp ( replace #include "cv.h" with #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" and remove "highgui.h" and replace the code on line 185 with the following code:

     ```
     int success = cvNamedWindow( "HandVu", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     //  if (success==0) {
     //    printf("can't open window - did you compile OpenCV with highgui support?");
     //    return -1;
     //  }
     ```